# How to paginate and group in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

My objects are of the following structure:

```
{id: 1234,  ownerId: 1,  typeId: 3456, date:...}
{id: 1235,  ownerId: 1,  typeId: 3456, date:...}
{id: 1236,  ownerId: 1,  typeId: 12, date:...}
```

I would like to query the database so that it returns all the items that belong to a given `ownerId` but only the first item of a given `typeId`. IE the `typeId` field is unique in the results. I would also like to be able to use `skip` and `limit`.

In SQL the query would be something like:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ownerId=1 SORT BY date GROUP BY typeId LIMIT 10 OFFSET 300`

I currently have the following query (using pymongo) but it is giving my errors for using `$sort`, `$limit` and `$skip`:

```
 search_dict['ownerId'] = 1
 search_dict['$sort'] = {'date': -1}
 search_dict['$limit'] = 10
 search_dict['$skip'] = 200

 collectionName.group(['typeId'], search_dict, {'list': []}, 'function(obj, prev) {prev.list.push(obj)}')
```

-

I have also tried the aggregation route but as I understand grouping will touch all the items in the collection, group them, and then limit and skip. This will be too computationally expensive and slow. I need an iterative grouping algorithm.

```
search_dict = {'ownerId':1}
collectionName.aggregate([
            {
                '$match': search_dict
            },
            {
                '$sort': {'date': -1}
            },
            {
                '$group': {'_id': "$typeId"}
            },
            {
                '$skip': skip
            },
            {
                '$limit': 10
            }
        ])
```

Comment: **The question needs to show your efforts to solve the problem yourself.** ;) After that, I'll happily answer.

Comment: Look into mongoose aggregate, give it a try and come back to us :)

Comment: @RichardMacarthy: Why mongoose? Pretty useless if OP is a Pythonista or a Coffee Cup (like me), isn't it?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg. I added my attempts at the solution.

Comment: When you are trying to derive the solution from an SQL query, then you are probably doing it wrong. MongoDB is not a relational database. Forget about groups and joins. Change the structure of your data. Denormalize. Add new collections. Don't be afraid of it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregation looks correct. You need to include the fields you want in the output in the `$group` stage using `$first`.

> grouping will touch all the items in the collection, group them, and then limit and skip. This will be too computationally expensive and slow.

It won't touch all items in the collection. If the match + sort is indexed (`{ "ownerId" : 1, "date" : -1 }`), the index will be used for the match + sort, and the group will only process the documents that are the result of the match.

The constraint is hardly ever cpu, except in cases of unindexed sort. It's usually disk I/O.

> I need an iterative grouping algorithm.

What precisely do you mean by "iterative grouping"? The grouping is iterative, as it iterates over the result of the previous stage and checks which group each document belongs to!

Answer (score -2):

I am not to sure how you get the idea that this operation should be computational expensive. This isn't really true for most SQL databases, and it surely isn't for MongoDB. All you need is to create an index over your sort criterium.

Here is how to prove it:

Open up a mongo shell and have this executed.

```
var bulk = db.speed.initializeOrderedBulkOp()
for ( var i = 1; i <= 100000; i++ ){
  bulk.insert({field1:i,field2:i*i,date:new ISODate()});
  if((i%100) == 0){print(i)}
}

bulk.execute();
```

The bulk execution may take some seconds. Next, we create a helper function:

```
Array.prototype.avg = function() {
  var av = 0;
  var cnt = 0;
  var len = this.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var e = +this[i];
    if(!e && this[i] !== 0 && this[i] !== '0') e--;
    if (this[i] == e) {av += e; cnt++;}
  }
  return av/cnt;
}
```

The troupe is ready, the stage is set:

```
var times = new Array();
for( var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
  var start = new Date();
  db.speed.find().sort({date:-1}).skip(Math.random()*100000).limit(10); 
  times.push(new Date() - start);
}
print(times.avg() + " msecs");
```

The output is in **[msecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond)**. This is the output of 5 runs for comparison:

1. 0.1697 msecs
2. 0.1441 msecs
3. 0.1397 msecs
4. 0.1682 msecs
5. 0.1843 msecs

The test server runs inside a docker image which in turn runs inside a VM (boot2docker) on my 2,13 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo with 4GB of RAM, running OSX 10.10.2, a lot of Safari windows, iTunes, Mail, Spotify and Eclipse additionally. Not quite a production system. And that collection does not even have an index on the date field. With the index, the averages of 5 runs look like this:

1. 0.1399 msecs
2. 0.1431 msecs
3. 0.1339 msecs
4. 0.1441 msecs
5. 0.1767 msecs

qed, hth.

Comment: Mind to explain the downvote, downvoter? Just curious and eager to improve.

Comment: @makuswmahlberg: I was not the person who down voted you but the query in your test is totally different than my query. This is because you are not grouping. Please re-do your test and have every 10 records share the same field2 value and then group by field2. Also try putting in 10 million records and random dates. 10 million is about the size of my collection.

Comment: Sure, will adjust that, was only for demonstration purposes. Will create the collection now, will take some time and it's getting late over here (CEST).

Comment: Every ten items share a typeId. So if there are ten million records then there are 1 million unique typeIds.

Comment: @Jakobovski: Last question is how many ownerIds you have (roughly).

Comment: 10,000 different owner ids